# Retrieve json value of javascript variable within index value function

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

How can I change this index value function to retrieve the gb value of the  "see": 8 variable of the "val": "West" group? Would an array work in this case?

It's logging the correct value for the gamesBack of the val.see == 8, but the ((val.gb - gamesBack) <= 4) and ((val.gb - gamesBack) > 4) equations are not computing correctly. I believe this is because the equations are not returning a value outside of the loop, but I'm not sure how to fix that.

```
  jQuery.each(sorted, function(i, val) {

  confStandings += (
    '<div class="team">');

  if (val.see == 8) {
    var gamesBack = val.gb;
  }                     
  console.log("gamesBack : ", gamesBack);


  if (val.see < 9) {
    confStandings += ('<div class="trow in ' + val.ta + '-row">');
  }
  if ((val.gb - gamesBack) <= 4) {
    confStandings += ('<div class="trow in-race ' + val.ta + '-row">');
  }
  if ((val.gb - gamesBack) > 4) {
    confStandings += ('<div class="trow out ' + val.ta + '-row">');
  }
  if(val.elim == 1){
    confStandings += ('<div class="trow out ' + val.ta + '-row">');
  }
});
```

Here's the data from the file.json: https://jsfiddle.net/istark/gj2okr47/

Here's a link to the full code for usage reference: https://jsfiddle.net/7py3ur5a/1/

Comment: can you add content of `file.json` in your jsfiddle provided ?Also you need to see if `see` has `8` and do some operation on it ?

Comment: I've updated the index value function to see if see has 8. I've also linked the content of the file.json file for reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare `gamesBack` globally so that you can use it anywhere in your code.Also,to get value of `see` we can use the `each(team..` loop which you already have in your code store the value of `gb` in `gamesBack` where `see = 8`.

**Demo Code** (I have removed ajax and 1st array under co because it was not needed in this demo ) :

```js
var data = {
  "sta": {
    "gdte": "2020-06-17",
    "co": [

      {
        "val": "West",
        "di": [{
            "val": "Northwest",
            "t": [{
                "tid": 1610612743,
                "see": 3,
                "cli": 1,
                "clid": 0,
                "clic": 0,
                "elim": 0,
                "str": "L 1",
                "l10": "5-5",
                "dr": "10-1",
                "cr": "26-13",
                "l": 22,
                "w": 43,
                "hr": "25-8",
                "ar": "18-14",
                "gb": 7.000,
                "gbd": 0.000,
                "gbl": "10.00000",
                "ta": "DEN",
                "tn": "Nuggets",
                "tc": "Denver"
              },
              {
                "tid": 1610612762,
                "see": 4,
                "cli": 1,
                "clid": 0,
                "clic": 0,
                "elim": 0,
                "str": "L 1",
                "l10": "5-5",
                "dr": "5-5",
                "cr": "21-16",
                "l": 23,
                "w": 41,
                "hr": "21-10",
                "ar": "20-13",
                "gb": 8.500,
                "gbd": 1.500,
                "gbl": "11.50000",
                "ta": "UTA",
                "tn": "Jazz",
                "tc": "Utah"
              },
              {
                "tid": 1610612760,
                "see": 5,
                "cli": 1,
                "clid": 0,
                "clic": 0,
                "elim": 0,
                "str": "W 3",
                "l10": "8-2",
                "dr": "7-4",
                "cr": "25-15",
                "l": 24,
                "w": 40,
                "hr": "20-13",
                "ar": "20-11",
                "gb": 9.500,
                "gbd": 2.500,
                "gbl": "12.50000",
                "ta": "OKC",
                "tn": "Thunder",
                "tc": "Oklahoma City"
              },
              {
                "tid": 1610612757,
                "see": 9,
                "cli": 0,
                "clid": 0,
                "clic": 0,
                "elim": 0,
                "str": "W 1",
                "l10": "4-6",
                "dr": "4-8",
                "cr": "16-26",
                "l": 37,
                "w": 29,
                "hr": "18-14",
                "ar": "11-23",
                "gb": 21.500,
                "gbd": 14.500,
                "gbl": "24.50000",
                "ta": "POR",
                "tn": "Trail Blazers",
                "tc": "Portland"
              },
              {
                "tid": 1610612750,
                "see": 14,
                "cli": 0,
                "clid": 0,
                "clic": 0,
                "elim": 1,
                "str": "L 3",
                "l10": "3-7",
                "dr": "2-10",
                "cr": "9-30",
                "l": 45,
                "w": 19,
                "hr": "8-24",
                "ar": "11-21",
                "gb": 30.500,
                "gbd": 23.500,
                "gbl": "33.50000",
                "ta": "MIN",
                "tn": "Timberwolves",
                "tc": "Minnesota"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "val": "Pacific",
            "t": [{
                "tid": 1610612747,
                "see": 1,
                "cli": 1,
                "clid": 0,
                "clic": 0,
                "elim": 0,
                "str": "L 1",
                "l10": "8-2",
                "dr": "9-2",
                "cr": "33-7",
                "l": 14,
                "w": 49,
                "hr": "23-8",
                "ar": "26-6",
                "gb": 0.000,
                "gbd": 0.000,
                "gbl": "3.00000",
                "ta": "LAL",
                "tn": "Lakers",
                "tc": "Los Angeles"
              },
              {
                "tid": 1610612746,
                "see": 2,
                "cli": 1,
                "clid": 0,
                "clic": 0,
                "elim": 0,
                "str": "W 1",
                "l10": "7-3",
                "dr": "8-4",
                "cr": "27-14",
                "l": 20,
                "w": 44,
                "hr": "25-7",
                "ar": "19-13",
                "gb": 5.500,
                "gbd": 5.500,
                "gbl": "8.50000",
                "ta": "LAC",
                "tn": "Clippers",
                "tc": "LA"
              },
              {
                "tid": 1610612758,
                "see": 11,
                "cli": 0,
                "clid": 0,
                "clic": 0,
                "elim": 0,
                "str": "L 1",
                "l10": "7-3",
                "dr": "7-5",
                "cr": "20-20",
                "l": 36,
                "w": 28,
                "hr": "14-17",
                "ar": "14-19",
                "gb": 21.500,
                "gbd": 21.500,
                "gbl": "24.50000",
                "ta": "SAC",
                "tn": "Kings",
                "tc": "Sacramento"
              },
              {
                "tid": 1610612756,
                "see": 13,
                "cli": 0,
                "clid": 0,
                "clic": 0,
                "elim": 0,
                "str": "L 1",
                "l10": "4-6",
                "dr": "5-9",
                "cr": "15-27",
                "l": 39,
                "w": 26,
                "hr": "13-22",
                "ar": "13-17",
                "gb": 24.000,
                "gbd": 24.000,
                "gbl": "27.00000",
                "ta": "PHX",
                "tn": "Suns",
                "tc": "Phoenix"
              },
              {
                "tid": 1610612744,
                "see": 15,
                "cli": 0,
                "clid": 0,
                "clic": 0,
                "elim": 1,
                "str": "L 1",
                "l10": "3-7",
                "dr": "2-11",
                "cr": "9-34",
                "l": 50,
                "w": 15,
                "hr": "8-26",
                "ar": "7-24",
                "gb": 35.000,
                "gbd": 35.000,
                "gbl": "38.00000",
                "ta": "GSW",
                "tn": "Warriors",
                "tc": "Golden State"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "val": "Southwest",
            "t": [{
                "tid": 1610612745,
                "see": 6,
                "cli": 1,
                "clid": 0,
                "clic": 0,
                "elim": 0,
                "str": "W 1",
                "l10": "6-4",
                "dr": "7-4",
                "cr": "25-17",
                "l": 24,
                "w": 40,
                "hr": "22-10",
                "ar": "18-14",
                "gb": 9.500,
                "gbd": 0.000,
                "gbl": "12.50000",
                "ta": "HOU",
                "tn": "Rockets",
                "tc": "Houston"
              },
              {
                "tid": 1610612742,
                "see": 7,
                "cli": 0,
                "clid": 0,
                "clic": 0,
                "elim": 0,
                "str": "W 1",
                "l10": "6-4",
                "dr": "10-3",
                "cr": "25-15",
                "l": 27,
                "w": 40,
                "hr": "19-15",
                "ar": "21-12",
                "gb": 11.000,
                "gbd": 1.500,
                "gbl": "14.00000",
                "ta": "DAL",
                "tn": "Mavericks",
                "tc": "Dallas"
              },
              {
                "tid": 1610612763,
                "see": 8,
                "cli": 0,
                "clid": 0,
                "clic": 0,
                "elim": 0,
                "str": "L 1",
                "l10": "4-6",
                "dr": "4-7",
                "cr": "19-22",
                "l": 33,
                "w": 32,
                "hr": "18-15",
                "ar": "14-18",
                "gb": 18.000,
                "gbd": 8.500,
                "gbl": "21.00000",
                "ta": "MEM",
                "tn": "Grizzlies",
                "tc": "Memphis"
              },
              {
                "tid": 1610612740,
                "see": 10,
                "cli": 0,
                "clid": 0,
                "clic": 0,
                "elim": 0,
                "str": "W 2",
                "l10": "5-5",
                "dr": "3-8",
                "cr": "17-25",
                "l": 36,
                "w": 28,
                "hr": "13-19",
                "ar": "15-17",
                "gb": 21.500,
                "gbd": 12.000,
                "gbl": "24.50000",
                "ta": "NOP",
                "tn": "Pelicans",
                "tc": "New Orleans"
              },
              {
                "tid": 1610612759,
                "see": 12,
                "cli": 0,
                "clid": 0,
                "clic": 0,
                "elim": 0,
                "str": "W 1",
                "l10": "5-5",
                "dr": "4-6",
                "cr": "15-21",
                "l": 36,
                "w": 27,
                "hr": "16-14",
                "ar": "11-22",
                "gb": 22.000,
                "gbd": 12.500,
                "gbl": "25.00000",
                "ta": "SAS",
                "tn": "Spurs",
                "tc": "San Antonio"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
};
var gbEight = ""; //decalre globally
jQuery(function() {



  var conference = data.sta.co[0];
  // console.log(conference);
  var confStandings = [];
  var games = [];
  var sorted;


  confStandings += (
    '<div class="standings col-md-12">\
        <div class="table">\
          <div class="thead">\
            <div class="tr">\
              <span data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Wins">W</span>\
              <span data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Losses">L</span>\
              <span data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Percentage">PCT</span>\
              <span data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Games Back">GB</span>\
              <span data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Home Record">HR</span>\
              <span data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Away Record">AR</span>\
              <span data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Division Record">DR</span>\
              <span data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Conference Record">CR</span>\
            </div>\
          </div>\
        <div class="tbody">'
  );
  var region = data.sta.co[0].di;
  jQuery.each(region, function(i, reg) {

    var team = reg.t;

    jQuery.each(team, function(i, name) {
      var eight = (name.see == 8);
      if (eight == true) {
        gbEight = (name.gb); //getting value of gb
        console.log(gbEight)
      }

      var wins = parseFloat(name.w);
      var losses = parseFloat(name.l);
      var total = wins + losses;
      var percent = (wins / total).toFixed(3);
      var width = (percent * 100).toFixed(1);
      var abbr = name.ta.toLowerCase();

      games.push({
        tid: name.tid,
        tn: name.tn,
        cli: name.cli,
        ta: abbr,
        wdth: width,
        w: name.w,
        l: name.l,
        pct: percent,
        gb: name.gb,
        hr: name.hr,
        ar: name.ar,
        dr: name.dr,
        cr: name.cr,
        see: name.see,
        elim: name.elim
      });

      sorted = games.sort(function(a, b) {


        if (a.see > b.see) {
          return 1;
        }
        if (a.see < b.see) {
          return -1;
        }
        return 0;
      });

    });
  });


  jQuery.each(sorted, function(i, val) {

    confStandings += (
      '<div class="team">');

    if (val.see < 9) {

      confStandings += ('<div class="trow in ' + val.ta + '-row">');
    }
    if (val.gb - gbEight <= 4) {

      confStandings += ('<div class="trow in-race ' + val.ta + '-row">');
    }
    if (val.gb - gbEight > 4) {
      confStandings += ('<div class="trow out ' + val.ta + '-row">');
    }
    if (val.elim == 1) {
      confStandings += ('<div class="trow out ' + val.ta + '-row">');
    }

    confStandings += (
      '<div class="tdata">\
          <div class="bar" style="width: ' + val.wdth + '%;"></div><div class="key">');
    if (val.see < 9) {
      confStandings += ('<small class="indicator see">' + val.see);
      if (val.cli > 0) {
        confStandings += ('x');
      }
      confStandings += ('</small>');
    }
    if (val.elim == 1) {
      confStandings += ('<small class="indicator elim">o</small>');
    }

    confStandings += ('</div><div class="logo ' + val.ta + '" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="' + val.tn + '">' + val.tn + '</div>\
          <div class="tstats">\
            <span data-title="W"><em>' + val.w + '</em></span>\
            <span data-title="L"><em>' + val.l + '</em></span>\
            <span data-title="PCT"><em>' + val.pct + '</em></span>\
            <span data-title="GB"><em>' + val.gb + '</em></span>\
            <span data-title="HR" class="hideMobile"><em>' + val.hr + '</em></span>\
            <span data-title="AR" class="hideMobile"><em>' + val.ar + '</em></span>\
            <span data-title="DR" class="hideMobile"><em>' + val.dr + '</em></span>\
            <span data-title="CR" class="hideMobile"><em>' + val.cr + '</em></span>\
          </div>\
        </div>\
      </div></div>');
  });
  confStandings += ('</div></div></div>');
  games = [];
  jQuery('#dataConfStandings').append(confStandings);


  function initToolTip() {
    jQuery('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
  }

  // Ordinals
  function ordinal_suffix(i) {
    var j = i % 10,
      k = i % 100;
    if (j == 1 && k != 11) {
      return i + "st";
    }
    if (j == 2 && k != 12) {
      return i + "nd";
    }
    if (j == 3 && k != 13) {
      return i + "rd";
    }
    return i + "th";
  }
});
```

```css
.in-race{
color : green;
}
.out {
color : red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dataConfStandings"></div>
```